# Help Pac-Man count the Pac-Dots

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, maze

On the advice of Ms. Pac-Man who's worried about him getting overweight, Pac-Man has decided to keep track of his daily Pac-Dot intake. Help him count the number of Pac-Dots on a given path in the maze!

### The maze

[image: maze]

To help you build your own encoding of the maze, you can **[get some raw data here](https://pastebin.com/3KkwaGyN)**.

### Pac-Man's journey

In the context of this challenge, the following rules apply:

- First, the good news: the ghosts aren't there.
- Pac-Man always starts his race at the position indicated on the above picture, heading to the East. There is no Pac-Dot at the starting position.
- As long as he's following a straight path, he keeps advancing to the next squares.
- When he encounters a *90° turn* without any other available path (orange squares on the map), he automatically and systematically takes the turn.
- When he encounters a *junction* where several paths are available (green squares on the map), he may either continue on the same direction -- if applicable -- or choose another direction (including doing a U-turn).
- When Pac-Man passes through one of the exits on the middle left or middle right side of the maze, he immediately reappears on the opposite side.
- Pac-Man eats all the Pac-Dots on the path he's following. Once a Pac-Dot has been eaten, it is removed from the maze.

### The challenge

#### Input

You'll be given a string describing Pac-Man's behavior on the junctions that he's going to reach. This string will be made of the following characters:

- `L`: do a 90° turn to the left
- `R`: do a 90° turn to the right
- `F`: go forwards (no direction change)
- `B`: go backwards (do a U-turn)

When all characters have been processed, Pac-Man stops at the next junction he encounters.

#### Output

You have to print or output the number of Pac-Dots eaten along the input path.

#### Rules

- You can write a full program or a function.
- You can take input in either uppercase or lowercase, as either a string or an array of characters. You may also use other characters (but only one character per direction) or integers in `[0 .. 9]`. If you do so, please specify it clearly in your answer.
- You can assume that the input is always valid. (The jsFiddle below will detect errors, but you're not supposed to.)
- This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes wins.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.

#### Hint

It may not be required nor optimal to store the exact shape of the maze.

### Test cases and demo

The following test cases -- or any other input -- **[can be tested in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arnauld/ww6b4n3v/1)**.

```
1. Input  : ""
   Output : 1
   Comment: Pac-Man just advances to the first junction, eats the Pac-Dot on it and stops.

2. Input  : "L"
   Output : 7
   
3. Input  : "FFR"
   Output : 13
   
4. Input  : "LFLR"
   Output : 17
   Comment: Pac-Man will exit on the middle right side and re-appear on the left side.
   
5. Input  : "BBBB"
   Output : 2
   
6. Input  : "BRRFFFL"
   Output : 15
   
7. Input  : "LFFRLFFFFRF"
   Output : 50
   
8. Input  : "BRFRLRFRLFR"
   Output : 54
   Comment: Pac-Man will exit on the middle left side and re-appear on the right side.
   
9. Input  : "FFLRLFFLLLLFFBFLFLRRRLRRFRFLRLFFFLFLLLLFRRFBRLLLFBLFFLBFRLLR"
   Output : 244
   Comment: All cleared!
```

Comment: Here's some more data to help out: https://pastebin.com/G4MnbVww . It's a list of every junction and the number of pac-dots on the road to the next junction depending on which direction you go (0=up, 1=left, 2=down, 3=right). There might be some errors, and keep in mind that junctions 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, and 19 have no dot in the middle, while all the others do.

Comment: @Challenger5 This is looking good. Because the moves are relative, you'd probably want to also keep track of the new orientation of Pac-Man when the next junction is reached, though.

Comment: BTW In the game pac man cannot do a u-turn

Comment: @SIGSEGV By 'u-turn', I just mean changing to the opposite direction, which is possible at any time in the original arcade game and all the clones I know. Should I use another term?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Pac-Man started heading left in the arcade game, not right.

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes, you are right. I shouldn't have relied on my aging memory and checked that only after posting. (Not that it changes anything to the challenge. ^^)

Comment: "You may also use other characters" - Can we use '\0', (char)1, (char)2, (char)3 instead of FLBR?

Comment: @ngn Do you mean NUL, SOH, STX, ETX? That's kinda unexpected but doesn't infringe the rules. So, yes. Digits would be fine as well (updated).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth, <s>356</s> 345 + 1 = 346 bytes

The code contains some unprintables, so here is the reversible `xxd` hexdump.

```
0000000: 4a4b 304c 2c3d 2b4b 4062 4a58 624a 3041  JK0L,=+K@bJXbJ0A
0000010: 2c63 6a43 2201 e120 49b4 efbc e267 27f4  ,cjC".. I....g'.
0000020: a11b f5d5 7f79 d1a0 ab8a 7689 449f 0c50  .....y....v.D..P
0000030: b2d4 7c30 99c3 368e aa67 4213 ab9b d276  ..|0..6..gB....v
0000040: d75f 6e99 5757 04a6 08cc 99d0 7141 3d2f  ._n.WW......qA=/
0000050: d854 7cf7 4a70 954e 6e35 f9b9 e0c5 1d53  .T|.Jp.Nn5.....S
0000060: 36d5 63f9 cf13 0f66 c113 4dec 956e 5225  6.c....f..M..nR%
0000070: b14a 1659 dcb5 6822 3534 2034 6a43 2203  .J.Y..h"54 4jC".
0000080: ffe3 8fff 2232 3d59 636a 4322 0b8a 4624  ...."2=YcjC"..F$
0000090: 7815 4a94 192c 79f6 d6e5 e098 5e97 76bc  x.J..,y.....^.v.
00000a0: 23cf 027c 35c5 5098 2a83 68f1 823a 83f6  #..|5.P.*.h..:..
00000b0: dfa4 7e12 443f 0257 7adb ab2d 8e6f 1199  ..~.D?.Wz..-.o..
00000c0: 9a3e 3f9d a524 d331 c5ff 94ae e5a2 3507  .>?..$.1......5.
00000d0: bd22 3334 2032 3d6b 2b30 6a43 2202 25f2  ."34 2=k+0jC".%.
00000e0: f55c 2252 c250 0002 c250 0000 065c 225c  .\"R.P...P...\"\
00000f0: 2247 5289 3698 4227 5350 8822 3136 3d64  "GR.6.B'SP."16=d
0000100: 636a 4322 8223 a80e 5c22 981d d272 729d  cjC".#..\"...rr.
0000110: d88d 981d 5c22 5c22 2bd7 91dd 9428 73d7  ....\"\"+....(s.
0000120: 1dd7 2234 2032 5651 2079 483d 547e 4a40  .."4 2VQ yH=T~J@
0000130: 4047 4a2b 5a78 2246 5242 4c22 4e20 796b  @GJ+Zx"FRBL"N yk
0000140: 3d5a 4040 647e 4a40 4059 4a3d 5421 7840  =Z@@d~J@@YJ=T!x@
0000150: 594a 5454 2968 7948 0a                   YJTT)hyH.
```

Requires the `-M` flag to disable memoization. Unfortunately, this can't be done in any online executor I know of.

Here is a <s>readable</s> printable ASCII version:

```
JK0L,=+K@bJXbJ0A,cj746957013238413906925468440008893181365431681519974815772691846219267045007717553452313017550830370829477591340658010575885616582299429376501117428763541235628345630376341520044712982918668584832091126800263024965443560007480163218792 54 4j17178005503 2=Ycj664551201217474826979459068682259492333017695780569003557724234375880492114440213266014621594427584622393511454741615093293082181365458295035985321888753898774398909 34 2=k+0j883734055588186287049718559289059922762611092840989558085734536 16=dcj53536195844172273707047543644202986760006840011986146398708374999 4 2VQ yH=T~J@@GJ+Zx"FRBL"N yk=Z@@d~J@@YJ=T!x@YJTT)hyH
```

### Explanation

This is very much work in progress, so I won't post a complete explanation yet.

Basically, the program represents the board as a (somewhat weird) graph using five lookup tables: 2 for connectivity, 1 for junction directions, and 2 for dot counts. This was built by a 200-line Python script I spent way too many hours on. Then the program just walks through the input and counts the dots, updating the dot tables to zero as the dots are collected.

#### TODO:

- Write Python routine for reordering the nodes until the lookup table contains as few escape-requiring characters as possible
- Try to remove section handling altogether (should remove one lookup table)

  - **UPDATE:** tried this, seems to not remove the table and lengthen code
- Rewrite Pyth-side logic (the current one isn't very golfed)

  - **UPDATE:** somewhat done, code's still imperfect

Comment: Why don't you just generate the URL so that you can run the real code on TIO? Maybe Dennis should add an easier way to do that.

Comment: @mbomb007 TIO doesn't support test suites (for Pyth, anyway), so I like to use Pyth's own host. Also, I'm not very confident with browsers handling null bytes correctly.

Comment: For the non-test suite, you could. And you can still code with nulls, you just can't copy/paste them, which is why you have to generate the URL.

Comment: Longest Pyth answer yet?

Comment: @LuisMendo At least for me, based on a quick search. :~)

Answer (score 2):

## k, 264 bytes

```
b:,/16 16\'108_a:-135#0+1:"p.k"
(#(?27,r 1)^(12+!8)^14 17)+/b@?*|r:+1 27 0{i:a?64/(4!2+y+*x;x 1);(4 64\a i+1-2*2!i),_i%2}\0:""
\
...binary data...
```

Hex dump:

```
$ xxd p.k
00000000: 623a 2c2f 3136 2031 365c 2731 3038 5f61  b:,/16 16\'108_a
00000010: 3a2d 3133 3523 302b 313a 2270 2e6b 220a  :-135#0+1:"p.k".
00000020: 2823 283f 3237 2c72 2031 295e 2831 322b  (#(?27,r 1)^(12+
00000030: 2138 295e 3134 2031 3729 2b2f 6240 3f2a  !8)^14 17)+/b@?*
00000040: 7c72 3a2b 3120 3237 2030 7b69 3a61 3f36  |r:+1 27 0{i:a?6
00000050: 342f 2834 2132 2b79 2b2a 783b 7820 3129  4/(4!2+y+*x;x 1)
00000060: 3b28 3420 3634 5c61 2069 2b31 2d32 2a32  ;(4 64\a i+1-2*2
00000070: 2169 292c 5f69 2532 7d5c 303a 2222 0a5c  !i),_i%2}\0:"".\
00000080: 0a02 4005 c006 4109 c103 8008 8143 c244  ..@...A......C.D
00000090: c345 c446 c547 c648 c749 c84a 820a 830c  .E.F.G.H.I.J....
000000a0: 840d 870b 8889 cb0e 8a11 8b0f 4c4d cc10  ............LM..
000000b0: cd4e d14f ce51 d014 8e12 8f13 9017 9153  .N.O.Q.........S
000000c0: d215 9216 931e 5455 d41a d51b 5657 d61f  ......TU....VW..
000000d0: d718 941d 9759 d85a d95b da5c db5d dc98  .....Y.Z.[.\.]..
000000e0: de20 9921 9c5f 9d5e 60df e161 e089 9833  . .!._.^`..a...3
000000f0: 4222 2247 2662 7550 0000 0500 5000 c255  B""G&buP....P..U
00000100: 2c22 2202 2588 5ff2                      ,"".%._.
```

The binary data at the end encodes two arrays:

- `a` consists of pairs of bytes, each representing (64*direction)+junctionId
- `b` is the number of Pacman dots between each pair of junctions in `a`

The program reads its own source file (`p.k`) and decodes the data.

The input comes from stdin and uses 0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03 (a.k.a. NUL,SOH,STX,ETX - the first four ASCII codes) instead of FLBR.

I use [my own implementation of k](https://github.com/ngn/k) which is limited, bloated, crashy, and slow compared to [the real thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_%28programming_language%29). I test with the following program:

```
t:{e:($y),"\n"; a:`sys[("/path/to/k";"./p.k");`c$"FLBR"?x]
   1@$[a~e;"ok\n";"failed ",x,"\n expected: ",e," actual: ",a,"\n"];}
t["";1]
t[,"L";7]
t["FFR";13]
t["LFLR";17]
t["BBBB";2]
t["BRRFFFL";15]
t["LFFRLFFFFRF";50]
t["BRFRLRFRLFR";54]
t["FFLRLFFLLLLFFBFLFLRRRLRRFRFLRLFFFLFLLLLFRRFBRLLLFBLFFLBFRLLR";244]
\
```

Comment: I compiled an interpreter for Linux (sorry, no Windows) and put the necessary files to run the tests here: https://github.com/ngn/tmp  To run them, just type: ./k t.k  If you still do need a download link for p.k: https://github.com/ngn/tmp/blob/master/p.k?raw=true